# How soon can I paint after filling cracks in a foundation?

Tags: paint, foundation, masonry

I have a foundation that I am trying to get back into shape.  I just wire brushed/scraped, power washed and dug out/filled in cracks using [Quikrete vinyl concrete patch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-40-lb-Concrete-Patch-113340/100318461#.UkdWsYakrtk).  I want to paint it now.

I would use a masonary primer and then a masonry paint like [this](http://www.homedepot.com/p/BEHR-Premium-1-gal-MS-39-Crystal-White-Elastomeric-Masonry-Stucco-and-Brick-Paint-06801/204166300?N=bbbj#.UkdXRoakrtk).  I want to know if I have to wait a certain amount of time to prime and paint.  I've seen on [some sites](http://www.houserepairtalk.com/f107/exterior-foundation-priming-painting-6423/) that fresh concrete should never be painted as the alkaline nature will "turn the paint to soap".  I don't know if the [Quikrete vinyl concrete patch](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-40-lb-Concrete-Patch-113340/100318461#.UkdWsYakrtk) is the same as concrete with alkalinity.  How should I proceed?

Comment: I would not deviate from the directions on the Quikcrete packaging, their website/FAQ or customer support phone number.

Comment: This is very product specific advice.  These are generally considered off topic as per the [faq]. The best answer is to follow manufacture recommendations.